# Scrolling to the top of the UISearchBar in a UITableView

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, uikit

I have a UITableView with a large header. At the bottom of the table view is a UISearchBar. When `searchBarShouldBeginEditing` fires, I want to scroll UITableView to the top of the screen with the search bar at the top

I tried something like this to no avail `tableView?.scrollRectToVisible(CGRect(x: 0, y: searchBar.frame.minY, width: view.frame.width, height: 400), animated: true)`

Would love some help. Thanks!

Comment: please describe in details or image to understand

Answer (score 1):

You can scroll to the top of the screen by

`tableView?.setContentOffset(CGPoint(x: 0, y: 0), animated: true)`

I think what you're looking for is either `tableView?.scrollRectToVisible(searchBar.frame, animated: true)` or `tableView?.setContentOffset(searchBar.frame.origin, animated: true)`

Comment: I have a header that's 300 points high and when the user starts searching, I want to scroll the table view so that the header is mostly hidden and the search bar is at the top

Comment: What? At the bottom of the table view is a UISearchBar and "with the search bar at the top" .I don't understand, what do you want?  provide design image?

Comment: I think what you're looking for is either
```tableView?.scrollRectToVisible(searchBar.frame, animated: true)```
or
```tableView?.setContentOffset(searchBar.frame.origin, animated: true)```